# Customize keyword lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting

I want to make appear "adriano@ubuntu:~$" in blue but I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.
I modified the example from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings).

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{green},    % comment style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  keepspaces=false,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=bash,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={adriano@ubuntu:~},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{red},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, title=Example]       
    adriano@ubuntu:~$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout dnsdist.key -x509 -days 365 -out dnsdist.pem #test
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Which give me the result :[image: Result]
Btw, I would also add the numerotation for my code, for example, instead of just example, display Code x.x example (like for the section).

Thx for the help,

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `morekeywords` use `otherkeywords`:

```
otherkeywords={adriano@ubuntu:~}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will read the difference between these two instructions :)